# GUI for Text Steganography C program

Tags: c, user-interface, steganography

How to develop a GUI for my program.I have made a c program to encrypt and decrypt any secret text message. I am hiding the message in the spaces between the words.

Comment: I'd like to see the reason behind downvoting! Including the answers!

Answer (score 1):

There are some GUI frameworks for C.

- [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) is one of the most used when porting Linux applications
- [IUP](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/) is very lightweight
- other listed on Google

However, my preferred solution to to add a rich GUI to C programs in a quick way, is to use [Tcl/Tk](http://www.tcl.tk/). You can separate completely your application from the interface, test the C code at your leisure using the command line and concentrate on the GUI as a separate effort.

There are two possible approaches for mixing Tcl/Tk and C:

- Create an executable and call it from the Tcl/Tk GUI with `[exec ... ]`
- Create a DLL and call the functions as tcl commands

The first approach is extremely easy but might be unsatisfactory from an esthetic point of view.

The second approach is a little bit more complex and has two variants: create a real tcl module or use `[ffidl][4]` to call the dll directly.  This time, the second is simpler than the former.

Finally, if you need to have a single, self-contained executable you can rely on [tclkit](http://code.google.com/p/tclkit/) which will embed everything you need in a single executable.

P.S. I see from one of you comments that your on Windows. You *can* create Windows GUI directly in C ([here](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/) is an old tutorial) but I can ensure you it's a real pain! If you want something more modern you have to switch to C++

Comment: Do we have any other frame works other than this because I have to implement it soon so can u suggest some easier frame work..???

Comment: IUP is rather simple (and you can benefit from his relationship with Lua so that you can create a Lua/C solution with an IUP interface). However, nothing I've seen is simpler than Tcl/Tk. You can do simple things simply and then move towards more complex interfaces. All the other GUI frameworks have a very steep learning curve.

Answer (score -1):

To develop your GUI, you could use GTK: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.90/ .

Comment: thanks..!!Can i use visual C++ for the same.??

Comment: @JabinGGeorge sure! Although if Visual C++ studio is what you use, then you don't even have to use gtk: you can use the windows api http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/207581-intro-to-the-windows-api/ (this is just part 1 of a series)